Does APIGEE have limit on the number of api calls it receives per second?
The api calls in my project goes this way:
Mobile --> APIGEE layer --> Service1 --> APIGEE layer --> Service2
So, I'm facing a timout issues happening when multiple calls are being made from Service1 to Service2 (happening in a loop).
For example, in single second I see some 10-11 calls are made from service1 to service2. I found out that first 10 calls are succesful, but 11 call timeoud out.
Similary In some other scenario, I see similar timed out issue with earlier calls were success.
So, I wanted to know whether there is a limit in APIGEE layer that can be configurable to handle multiple requests in single second/minute ?
I looked into the page: https://cloud.google.com/apigee/docs/api-platform/reference/limits
I see that User, service account, or Apigee UI initiated ==>    6,000 per minute . So here can I finalize that 100 per second is what APIgee allows ?
Any thoughts or suggestions (because not worked on APIgee before) ?

Apigee, from a capacity sense, can definitely handle APIs which run at rates far higher. 100 calls per second (transactions per second, or TPS) is below 1% of the sustained rate that some Apigee customers configure for and see in daily production activity. You may though have a policy applied in your proxy definition which artificially constrains traffic flow; that’s common to protect one’s own backend services. If in doubt, talk to Apigee Support.
